# Creating a unicode XML file in Python 2.7.1

Tags: python, xml, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to write some data out into a unicode XML file with the following statement:

```
filepath = 'G:\Kodi EPG\ChannelGuide.xml'
with open(filepath, "w", encoding = 'UTF-8') as xml_file:
    xml_file.write(file_blanker)
xml_file.close
```

...but am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python27\Kodi\Sky TV Guide Scraper.py", line 35, in <module>
    class tv_guide:
  File "G:\Python27\Kodi\Sky TV Guide Scraper.py", line 47, in tv_guide
    with open(filepath, "w", encoding = 'UTF-8') as xml_file:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I have seen this given as an accepted answer on here to a question, but that was for Python 3xx. Is the syntax slightly different for version 2?

Thanks

Comment: Yes in python 2.7 just use `with open(filepath, "w")`

Comment: I need it to save in UTF-8 format though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is different for Python2 - regarding the `encoding` argument.

Python2 [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) description:

```
open(name[, mode[, buffering]])
```

Python3 [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) description:

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

As you can see, in Python 2.7 `open` doesn't accept the `encoding` argument, hence the Type Error.

However you can use the built-in [`io`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#module-io) module to open your files.  This would allow you to specify the encoding, and also provide compatibility with Python3. For example,

```
import io

filepath = r'G:\Kodi EPG\ChannelGuide.xml'
with io.open(filepath, "w", encoding = 'UTF-8') as xml_file:
    xml_file.write(file_blanker)
```

Note that you don't have to explicitly close your files when using the the `with` statement.

Comment: Hi @t.m.adam, I got stuck solving another issue. I'll be very happy if you care to take a look at ***[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063302/unable-to-make-my-script-produce-a-particular-output)*** in case there is a solution in your mind. Thanks a zillion in advance.