# Unable to make my script produce a particular output

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a script in Python to fetch all the links connected to the name of different actors from imdb.com and then parse the first three of their movie links and finally scrape the name of director and writer of those movies. There are around 1000 names in there. I'm okay with the first three names for this example.

**[Website link](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls058011111/)**

I can scrape the links of different `actors` and their first three movie `links` in one go.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/list/ls058011111/'
base = 'https://www.imdb.com/'

def get_actor_list(s):
    res = s.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for name_links in soup.select(".mode-detail")[:3]:
        name = name_links.select_one("h3 > a").get_text(strip=True)
        item_link = urljoin(base,name_links.select_one("h3 > a").get("href"))
        yield from get_movie_links(s,name,item_link)

def get_movie_links(s,name,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    item_links = [urljoin(base,item.get("href")) for item in soup.select(".filmo-category-section .filmo-row > b > a[href]")[:3]]
    yield name,item_links

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        for elem in get_actor_list(s):
            print(elem)
```

The result I get:

```
('Robert De Niro', ['https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4075436/', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3143812/', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5537002/'])
('Jack Nicholson', ['https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1341188/', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1356864/', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0825232/'])
('Marlon Brando', ['https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10905860/', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0442674/', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1667880/'])
```

I can even parse the name of `directors` and the `writers` of those linked movies if I individually use those links within the following function:

```
def get_content(s,url):
    res = s.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    director = soup.select_one("h4:contains('Director') ~ a")
    director = director.get_text(strip=True) if director else None
    writer = soup.select_one("h4:contains('Writer') ~ a").get_text(strip=True)
    print(director,writer)
```

However, I would like to rectify the script merging those functions in such a way so that it produces the following (final) output:

```
('Robert De Niro', [Jonathan Jakubowicz, Jonathan Jakubowicz,  None, Anthony Thorne, Martin Scorsese, David Grann])
('Jack Nicholson', [James L. Brooks, James L. Brooks, Casey Affleck, Casey Affleck, Rob Reiner, Justin Zackham])
('Marlon Brando', [Bob Bendetson, Bob Bendetson, Peter Mitchell, Rubin Mario Puzo, Paul Hunter, Paul Hunter])
```

How can I get the final output merging the above functions in the right way?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the problem. Your function to get the director and writer work, right?

Comment: Which portion of the probelm you find trouble understanding  @Alexander Cécile? The function does really works but it is unable to produce the output the way the final output looks like. Thanks.

Comment: Since you already have the `get_content()` function, just change it to return `(director,writer)` and yield the return value and `name` in `get_movie_links()`. I could get the required format with this small change: `yield name, [i for url in item_links for i in get_content(s, url)]` in `get_movie_links()`. The inner for loop unpacks the results of `get_content()`, if you skip it you'll get the director and writer in pairs.

Comment: You are the legend @t.m.adam. I still can't believe that the issue is fixed. Thanks a lot.